# Custom ProgressDialog inside antoher dialog issue

Tags: android, android-layout

I'm having troubles creating custom rounded ProgressDialog.

Here is my rounded shape:

roundeddialog.xml

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>
<shape xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android">
    <solid android:color="#FFCCCCCC"/>

<corners android:bottomRightRadius="7dp" android:bottomLeftRadius="7dp" 
 android:topLeftRadius="7dp" android:topRightRadius="7dp"/> 
</shape>
```

loadprogressdialog.xml is my style:

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>
<resources xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android">
    <style name="NewDialog" parent="@android:style/Theme.Dialog">

     <item name="android:windowBackground">@android:color/transparent</item>
     <item name="android:textColor">#000000</item>     
     <item name="android:background">@drawable/roundeddialog</item>

</style>
</resources>
```

My java code:

```
ProgressDialog dialog = new ProgressDialog(activity,R.style.NewDialog);        
dialog.setMessage(loadDialogMessage); 
dialog.show();
```

What shown is:

[image]

I don't want the inner dialog, just the outer one with the rounded corners.

I can't figure out why the inner dialog is created.

Can someone help ?

Answer (score 0):

If I have not misunderstood your issue, you should add to NewDialog

```
<item name="android:windowFrame">@null</item>
```